# SQL Query with the Northwind database (Catch: no Inner Join)

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

First and foremost - it is a homework assignment, yet I am not asking for anyone to do it. Instead I need help with how to construct the query.

As part of an assignment, using the Northwind database via Microsoft Access, I have to construct this query:

> The product ID, product name, and quantity ordered for all products ordered  on an order taken by an employee with last name Fuller.

Now, when I construct the query in design mode, this is the code I get:

```
SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.ProductName, [Order Details].Quantity
FROM Products INNER JOIN ((Employees INNER JOIN Orders ON Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID) INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON Orders.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID) ON Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
WHERE (((Employees.LastName)="Fuller"));
```

As I mentioned earlier, we are not allowed to use Inner Join. After scouring the text/notes thus far I can't find how to go about it. (Very new to SQL)

Would I be rewriting the FROM statement? And if so, do the SELECT and WHERE statements change?

**UPDATE:** Here is the code as I rewrote it:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.CustomerID, Orders.ShipCity
FROM Products, Orders, [Order Details], Employees
WHERE
  Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID
  AND Employees.EmployeeID = Orders.EmployeeID
  AND Ordes.OrderID = [Order Details].OrderID
  AND Employees.LastName = "Fuller";
```

I'm having a sort of syntax issue though. Since the Order Details must be enclosed in brackets, it wants to ask for parameter values for what I wrote in the WHERE statement.

Comment: An `IN ()` subquery like `WHERE somecolumn IN (SELECT somecommonvale FROM othertable)` is often a possibility, but more complicated when dealing with more than 2 tables (you appear to have 4)

Comment: I do. Because of the way the tables are set up, the Product's ID and name can be pulled from the Product table, but the quantity ordered must go through Orders -> Order details, because the Employee name (Fuller is what I am looking for) is in the Orders table, while the quantity is in the Order Details table.

Comment: Well, it could be rewritten using multiple _nested_ `IN (SELECT...)` subqueries, but this is a peculiar request because the  presence of columns from more than one table in the `SELECT` list implies some sort of join. Is it possible what's being asked is to use an _implicit join_, where multiple tables are listed in the `FROM` clause and related in `WHERE` like `FROM Products, Orders, [Order Details], Employees WHERE Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID AND....`

Comment: Doing it that way does not explicitly use `INNER JOIN` but still manages to join the tables using an older joining syntax...

Comment: Okay, trying that now. I'm trying to track my professors reasoning...is there a reason you wouldn't want to use Inner Join?

Comment: I can see wanting you to understand the `IN (SELECT...)` method, but that isn't really available to you with so many tables and a complex SELECT list.  Using the implicit (comma separated FROM) joining syntax is generally not preferable to explicit INNER JOINs, but you may be intended to learn it.

Comment: The basic format (and pros/cons) is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Comment: Also: I have rewritten it the way you suggested, but for whatever reason Order Details was in brackets. When I leave it in brackets, I of course get the  input window for orderID, but when I remove them it gives a syntax error. Is this because the name is two words?

Comment: That I can't really answer - Did you include _all_ the relationships in the `WHERE`? If the order Id is ambiguous, Access may prompt for it, but if all the joins are represented then it shouldn't be ambiguous. It _must_ be bracketed though.

Comment: Updated to show how I rewrote it.

Comment: @Monobus The latest revision includes `Ordes.OrderID`  Does your query work after you correct that table name?

Comment: Typo here - `Ordes` instead of `Orders` --  maybe that's what access is prompting?  `AND Ordes.OrderID`

Comment: @HansUp That was it! Wow, silly me. I appreciate the point out.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I really appreciate the help in showing me the explicit joining and also pointing our my error. Hopefully I can figure out the rest of the queries no problem.

Comment: @Monobus I'm not sure this fulfills your instructor's requirement, but I'll summarize this as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirement not to use `INNER JOIN` is a little peculiar and I cannot guarantee this is what was intended for your assignment.

One way to alternatively write a simplistic relationship between two tables is with an `IN ()` subquery, the general form being:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_table
WHERE some_column IN (
  SELECT some_related_column
  FROM b_table
  WHERE some_condition
)
```

But since you must represent columns from more than one of your 4 tables in the `SELECT` list, that form isn't going to work for you.  Another way of not *explicitly* using an `INNER JOIN` is to use the older implicit joining syntax, in which multiple tables are listed in the `FROM` clause separated by commas, and their joining conditions placed in the `WHERE` clause instead of in `ON`.

The general form is:

```
SELECT 
  a_table.col1,
  a_table.col2,
  b_table.col1
FROM
  a_table,
  b_table
WHERE
 a_table.some_column = b_table.some_related_column
 AND some_other_conditions
```

It being an assignment, I will leave it to you to work out the entire statement, but yours would take a form like

```
SELECT
  Orders.OrderID,
  Orders.CustomerID
FROM 
  Products,
  Orders,
  [Order Details],
  Employees
WHERE
  Products.ProductID = [Order Details].ProductID 
  AND ... (the other table relationships)
  AND Employees.LastName = 'Fuller'
```

Although it is functionally identical to explicit `INNER JOIN`s, this is an older syntax, and is often discouraged nowadays. [More discussion is available in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins)

Comment: Considering the prompt was concise and the only disclaimer was not to use Inner Join, I feel like this was correct. I've already knocked out a few more queries thanks to your pointers.